# How to create subset using mosaic for seasons

Tags: r, mosaic

So I am a total beginner. For my project, I am just using RStudio with mosaic.

I have a dataset with 10 variables, describing in which month of 2019 what kind of accident happend, who was involved (car, bike, ...) and its outcome (deadly, slight injury, heavy injury)

I want to combine all wintermonths (Dezember, Januar, Februar) in one subset (season winter) to be able to compare them with the non winter months

I used

```
data_winter <- select (Berlin, UMONAT=="Dezember" & UMONAT=="Januar" & UMONAT=="Februar")
```

But it just gives out:

> Error: object 'UMONAT' not found

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

[image]

```
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13389L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(UANZAHL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), UMONAT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UWOCHENTAG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UKATEGORIE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstRad = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstPKW = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstFuss = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstKrad = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstGkfz = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), IstSonstige = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Please paste the output of ``dput(Berlin)`` into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for coming back and trying to help.

Comment: It seems like you've missed off the first part of the ``dput()`` output when you pasted it in (it should start with `structure(...`. It's important to paste the entire output in. If it's too big, then try ``dput(head(Berlin))``. Thanks.

Comment: @Jay it seems like you read in the data from an excel file? can sou share what the output of str(Berlin) is? ... it might not be necessary to separate the data as you can handle it in grouping in one df with dplyr, depending on the case ...